# How to extract specific terms from a field during indexing and copy the terms to another field?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I am indexing this document to elasticsearch:

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/vendor_v2/items/1?pretty' -d '{
  "title": "Pretty Hats - Green Hat for bold head",
  "url": "http://hatshop.com/greenhat",
  "timestamp": "2014-11-28T23:40:36.630917",
  "regularPrice": "16,34",
  "id": "1a99c2871df4351044f32c96b96c93d1"
}'
```

I would like to use a plugin, script or analyzer that takes the terms found in the "title" field (whitespace based tokenizer) and runs them against three "term lists" (list with brand names, list with colors and list with product types).

Matching terms shall be copied to three new fields in the indexed document. The final indexed document should look like this.

```
{
  "title": "Pretty Hats - Green Hat for bold head",
  "color": "green",
  "brand": "Pretty Hats",
  "productType": "Hat",
  "url": "http://hatshop.com/greenhat",
  "timestamp": "2014-11-28T23:40:36.630917",
  "regularPrice": "16,34",
  "id": "1a99c2871df4351044f32c96b96c93d1"
}
```

Is this possible with elasticsearch while indexing? Or do I need to take care of that in my application?

Comment: I believe a starting point and experimentation could be done with [transform](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-transform.html#mapping-transform).

Comment: indeed looks promising

Comment: looked at it. I need to store the final document in the _source field. transform only manipulates the indexed data but not the _source field. thanks anyway!

Comment: @Jabb: Have you found any solution for this ?

Comment: yeah sort sort of... we are doing this using python by means of a small middleware script